# Bad sides of C2dM

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

We all know that as of Android 2.2 a push notification system exists (C2dM). However, I do not see many developers using it. 
In my next project I plan (hope so) to use this system. So before I dig into it, I would like to know what are the bad sides of it? Why people do not use it?

It can't be just because of incompatibility with systems older that 2.2.

Comment: My Google Market stats tell me that 33% of my users are running Android versions earlier than 2.2. So the need to provide a workaround for legacy devices is still very much there.

Comment: This is true. I really hate the limitation to 2.2+. At least, without providing a quality solution/tutorial for older phones. So they really expect from us to make push notifications for one part of phones and polling for others?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice question. Here is my 2 cents :

1. C2DM is still in beta
2. There is a    limit on the number of messages you  can send. If you need to send a large    number of messages, then you need to    explain it to Google and get it    approved.
3. The device must have    Android market with one google    account signed in.
4. The documentation    is a bit flaky [My personal opinion].    e.g. The signup form asks for the app    package name and the ROLE account ID on the same page providing wrong    impression that once signed up, the  package name is bound to the ROLE    account ID and can only receive    messages from it.

I don't think people are not using it. Rather I find most developers are very much interested in it and are implementing it. My [C2DM post](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-c2dm-messaging-server-push-for.html) has the most visitors of all my posts.

However the problem might be for individual developers who develop stand alone apps. They may be reluctant to use it since they will require to maintain a server side component to push messages.

[Will update my ans. if I find anything else.]

Comment: So the framework is still not ready to invest your time learning it? What do you think if it will last or there is a chance they will cancel and and introduce something better?

Comment: Google's development has always been incremental. Every product they launched was Beta first and then the progressed and improved from there. They are aware that people use this and won't drastically change anything that will affect. Hence I feel it is worth looking into it, learn it, try to understand the design decisions. It is only going to improve !

Answer (score 2):

I think a lot don't use it because

- They have no real need for it
- So far it isn't very straight forward
- Stated above, it is in beta still.

With Apple Push, it is pretty straight forward (on the device side), you simply invoke a call and it gives you the device token. With C2DM, you have to (though you can dig for the google account) prompt the user for the google account, then you have to hope they don't have too many Apps already registered for C2DM (100 limit now).

Server side, I'd say C2DM is a lot easier than push, you simply are invoking a service, with APNS you need to setup pipes, use certificates, etc. It isn't easy for most to do. C2DM is just invoking a HTTP call. The server aspect adds a bit of expense as well, hosting application services isn't always cheap.

I don't see a lot of Apps having the need for it, so far Twitter and Facebook seem to be (Though they may be using something else, I am not sure).

And, it is still a beta service. Do developers want to invest a lot of time in a beta service? Not all do, some will take the risks.

I've used it and I like it, I have it coupled with APNS and have had great success so far.

Comment: So the framework is still not ready to invest your time learning it? What do you think if it will last or there is a chance they will cancel and and introduce something better?

Comment: I have been using it personally, I am betting that it will be what Google uses in the long run. I would assume they would make improvements, hopefully some of the oddities will be sorted out by then. It looks promising... We shall see.